# Why does my WinForms UserControl stop firing Paint events when BorderStyle = None?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I've just tracked down a problem, where one one of my UserControls mysteriously stopped firing Paint events.

Turns out the BorderStyle had been accidently set to None.  When I set it back to FixedSingle, the Paint events started firing again.

This surprised the heck out of me - any idea why this is happening?

**edit**
The UserControl is based on a 3rd party control [(ASE ChartDirector)](http://www.advsofteng.com/cdnet.html), and we had another problem with it.  When it's BackColor was set to Transparent, it would fire Paint events **continuously**!. The workaround in that case was to set BackColor to ControlLightLight.
[(see this question for more details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512249/winforms-tabcontrol-causing-spurious-paint-events-for-usercontrol)

Could that also be a clue to the BorderStyle problem?

Comment: That's weird. I use BorderStyle.None on most my user controls and their Paint events still fire.

Comment: Post code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @Hans - I'll try, but that could be difficult - please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that will be difficult.  You are using a control which a huge chunk of code behind it that you don't have access to whose sole purpose in life is to custom paint.  Contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very nice blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx) discussing in very detail the reason for that.

Update: This article is for WPF however, both WPF and Windows Forms touch HWND, WParam, LParam at some point.

Here is why I think that the paint events might not get processed (Text below is as it appears on the article).

> The operating system must respond very quickly to mouse movement. 
>   Windows uses a dedicated Raw Input Thread (RIT), running in the
>   kernel, to handle the signals from the mouse hardware.  The RIT
>   quickly scans over the HWND hierarchy to see which window the mouse is
>   over.  Because the system must be responsive, no application code is
>   invoked.  For normal windows, the RIT checks the mouse position
>   against the window's rectangle (or region, if one is set).  But for
>   layered windows, the RIT looks in the bitmap that specifies the
>   content for the window and checks the effective transparency at that
>   location (which can be affected by the constant opacity setting, the
>   color key setting, or the per-pixel alpha channel).  If the pixel is
>   100% transparent, the RIT skips the window and keeps looking.  Once a
>   window has been located, the mouse move flag is set on the thread that
>   owns the window.  This will cause the thread to receive a WM_MOUSEMOVE
>   message the next time it calls GetMessage() and there are no other
>   higher-priority messages.

While this is particularly for messages coming from mouse hardware signals, I though that something similar could happen with other events too.

Here is what I would do,

Inside the Form class have the following code execute in order to watch the messages that are processed.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(m.Msg + ":" + m);
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I searched but could not get more information around.

Comment: Windows supports transparency at the HWND level through a feature called "layered windows".

Comment: You really need to point at a paragraph in the linked post and say: "Here!  That's why your UserControl doesn't repaint when it is borderless".  Layering is only supported for toplevel windows.  Forms.

Comment: @Nikos - I skimmed the blog post, but it's for WPF (which I've never used), not Winforms. Also, I don't see any mention of borders at all.  You may be on the right track, however - the control does use transparency.  How would I determine if it is using Layered Windows?

Comment: @Tom Bushell - I update the answer with my thoughts. Feel free to mark as not useful if you feel so :( I could not get more information around.

Comment: @Nikos - thanks for the clarification, and also the overriding WndProc trick - that's a new one for me.